# How do you test a service that makes call to another API endpoint in Go?

Tags: go, tdd, bdd

I have a simple service created using infinite loop to call a certain HTTP API periodically, implemented in a package `aservice`. I created a `Service` struct there. Typically, to run that service, I expose a `StartService` method which is used to run that service synchronously. Users of the package can then run it using a goroutine. My question is, how do you write the tests for this kind of scenario?

Do you run the whole system and "mock" the API? I have heard that code that uses 3rd party services don't need to be tested, but the whole `aservice` package may only contain `StartService` and `Shutdown` methods. The rest of them are unexported functions/methods which are then cannot be tested individually. If that is the case then I can't write any tests at all?

Comment: What are you testing? Are you testing if the response you got from the API is processed correctly? If so, you can extract the logic that processes the API output to unexported functions and write tests for those. If you're testing if the call to the API is prepared correctly? Then mock the API and test the request.

Comment: Yes I'm actually aiming to test both. But the problem here I think is more of the API mocking. Your comment just gave me one answer about the testing scenario. Maybe give me a detail about the mock part? If you do mock the API, that means there is a server that you need to start separately right? Doesn't that get a little bit messy especially for parallel tests?

Comment: You can mock it with a test server using net/http/httptest package. Or, you can mock the API call without the HTTP bits by refactoring the HTTP parts out to a struct, and passing a separate implementation of that struct during the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Go you will have awesome experience while mocking external http requests. Long story short just substitute base url with server url from net/http/httptest package.
You can mimic the way Google mocks their external requests for example exploring tests in google maps [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-go/blob/e6c76e578df330b3985c79df687a6c2953f450f3/directions_test.go#L41).

```
server := mockServer(200, response)
defer server.Close()
c, _ := NewClient(WithAPIKey(apiKey), WithBaseURL(server.URL))
r := &DirectionsRequest{
    Origin:      "Google Sydney",
    Destination: "Glebe Pt Rd, Glebe",
    Mode:        TravelModeTransit,
}

resp, _, err := c.Directions(context.Background(), r) 
// your assertions goes here


 // Create a mock HTTP Server that will return a response with HTTP code and body.
func mockServer(code int, body string) *httptest.Server {
    server := mockServerForQuery("", code, body)
    return server.s
}

func mockServerForQuery(query string, code int, body string) *countingServer {
    server := &countingServer{}

    server.s = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if query != "" && r.URL.RawQuery != query {
            dmp := diffmatchpatch.New()
            diffs := dmp.DiffMain(query, r.URL.RawQuery, false)
            log.Printf("Query != Expected Query: %s", dmp.DiffPrettyText(diffs))
            server.failed = append(server.failed, r.URL.RawQuery)
            http.Error(w, "fail", 999)
            return
        }
        server.successful++

        w.WriteHeader(code)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        fmt.Fprintln(w, body)
    }))

    return server
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the httptest package, this is so that I don't have to spawn a separate servers right? Kinda complicated especially for running it with CI server if I had to spawn a separate dummy server. This kind of test is still called unit test? Or behavioral test?